# How to link metal utility shaders with local executable metal library using SPM

Tags: metal, swift-package-manager

The idea is having a Utilities.metal shader with **helper functions** (let's say converting color: rgb2hsv(), ... ) that I want to **reuse in many projects**. I'd like to access from the local project's metal shader files those helper functions while sharing it as a swift package.

Goals:

- Having a Utilities.metal shader file or files in a swift package that I can add to other projects.
- Calling that rgb2hsv() function from local shaders. I want to **access the functions** on that Utilities.metal file from a local executable metal library's (the one that you create in the local project with `MTLDevice.makeDefaultLibrary()` shaders (doing #include "Utilities.h" in local metal shaders?).
- I want the package to contain the .metal files so I can update and commit them from any project (as local package in tandem with the app) not just the metallib.

What I don't want:

- Making the bundle library `MTLDevice.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle:)` to use it inside the package or locally as a stand alone library. I want to link the functions and have access to them.
- Avoid if possible hacky things like converting the shaders files to strings and using `MTLDevide.makeLibrary(source: source options: nil)`.

Do I need to use `MTLDynamicLibrary`? The problem is it's not supported on many devices. Any help is welcome.